# How to reference to java class in avro

Tags: avro

I have ClassA Created in java which has some custom annotation which i can't create a part of the avro record. i would like to define protocol rpc in avro to return the custom java class.

Something like:

```
@namespace("org.test.avro.service")   protocol TestService {
org.test.avro.domain.ClassA methodA(); }
```

It says org.apache.avro.compiler.idl.ParseException: Undefined name 'org.test.avro.domain.ClassA'

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to represent your Java class as an Avro record in order to use it in Avro definitions. If the class and the service share the same namespace, then the record can be defined in the same protocol definition, but since yours has a different namespace, define it in a separate avdl file.

```
@namespace("org.test.avro.domain")   protocol TestServiceDependency {

  record org.test.avro.domain.ClassA {

    int fieldA; } }
```

Then import it into your TestService protocol.

```
@namespace("org.test.avro.service")   protocol TestService {

  import idl "dependency.avdl";

  org.test.avro.domain.ClassA methodA(); }
```

When you try to parse with `new Idl(testservice.avdl)`, Avro will look in same directory for any imported files and parse them first.